# What is the expected value of the volume of a tetrahedron inscribed in the unit sphere?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, integration, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, spherical-geometry

Four (non-coincident) points on the unit sphere determine a tetrahedron. What is the expected value of the volume of such a tetrahedron--the volume of the sphere itself being $\frac{4 \pi}{3} \approx 4.18879$?

This is a variant--stripped of the quantum-information-theoretic details there--of a problem I just posed in the last paragraph of [QuantumSteeringEllipsoidVolume](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.09152.pdf)  .

In [TetrahedronVolume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron), the volume of a tetrahedron is expressed as
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{6} |\mbox{det}(\bf{a-d},\bf{b-d},\bf{c-d})|,
\end{equation}
where the vertices of the tetrahedron are ${\bf{a}}=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\},
{\bf{b}}=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\},{\bf{c}}=\{c_1,c_2.c_3\},{\bf{d}}=\{d_1,d_2,d_3\}$.

Can/should each vertex be considered as independent of the other three?

Comment: If the points are chosen uniformly and independently, then all you have to do is integrate your formula for the tetrahedron volume with respect to each variable over the unit sphere with normalized surface measure.  This should be straightforward to do in spherical coordinates,  especially if you use a CAS to do the integral.  If you want dependence or some other joint distribution, then you have to specify what that should be.

Comment: Also note that by invariance you can fix one of the vertices, setting e.g. $\mathbf{a}=\langle0,0,1\rangle$, and then integrate over the other three.

Comment: Thanks, Nate Eldredge! CAS? Also, doesn't the absolute value function in the volume formula complicate the indicated integrations? I'll give it all a whirl.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not a big fan of CAS but I agree that it is a good test to see if it is worth anything. The answer is $4\pi/105$, of course (pen, paper, and a little bit of trickery) ;-)

Comment: @PaulB.Slater: "CAS" = "Computer Algebra System": Mathematica / Maple / Sage / SymPy / what have you.

Comment: (1) Thanks, fedja! Posting an answer would certainly be appreciated; (2) Nate Eldredge: I'm a Mathematica devotee https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29989/paul-b-slater; (3) It seems that I need to "twiddle" the $\frac{4 \pi}{105}$ to answer the specific question I pose at the end of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.09152.pdf where I seek to normalize the "volume of nested tetrahedra" by the "volume of quantum steering ellipsoids". Some pondering on my part to do (maybe some further clarification of this by me).

Comment: @PaulB.Slater Do you mean the "*problem of estimating/determiningthe ratio (certainly greater than 0.0288) of the volume of nested tetrahedra to the volume of all ellpsoids*"? If so, can you state it in full in purely mathematical terms (it is a little bit hard to extract the exact statement from the paper without reading it carefully). And yes, I'll post the computation of the mean volume of the tetrahedron with 4 independent vertices on the sphere, but later: I want to give the CAS fans a chance to do their "straightforward computation" first :-)

Comment: @fedja. Thanks for the request. Here goes--Every point in a certain 15-dimensional space gets mapped to an ellipsoid in the unit 3D-ball. Some of these ellipsoids fit into a nested tetrahedron, and others don't. The  0.0288 is the estimated ratio of the integral of the volumes of the fitting ellipsoids to the integral of the volumes of all ellipsoids. So, clearly the ratio of the integral of the volumes of the tetrahedra to, again,  the integral of the volumes of all ellipsoids should be greater than the 0.0288.

Comment: Erm... Am I the only one who still has trouble understanding what Paul really wants after his last clarification? I mean, it is still quite unclear to me what "a nested tetrahedron" is: I surmise it should be squeezed between the ellipsoid and the unit ball, but then, when it exists, it doesn't need to be unique, so what volume are we talking about? Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: @fedja. Thanks for your attention, again. You may have a point here. There are two classes of ellipsoids in this setting. Those that fit into tetrahedra within the unit 3D-ball, and those that don't. (Apparently, an important distinction--since the former ellipsoids correspond to "separable" states and the latter, "entangled" states.) Perhaps there is no uniqueness to the tetrahedron (nor, then, the volume) within which an ellipsoid lies. So, maybe the question (undoubtedly challenging) to be asked--if any--is what is the minimal volume for such containing ellipsoids. (continued,next comment).

Comment: The founding paper in this area https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.4724.pdf is quite mathematical in character. "Nested tetrahedra" are discussed in detail--but, off-hand, I see no claim of uniqueness, or one-to-oness between ellipsoids and tetrahedra.